# JPA: How to handle this case of ManyToMany

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

The situation I am trying to handle is an Account can have multiple Positions. This would normally be one-to-many and I think would simply be within Account there would be a List with the one-to-many annotation and in Position, an Account with the many-to-one annotation. However, not only is there the Account which currently holds the Position but it might also be possible that there is another Account which is the Account which shorted the Position.

The way I would like to handle this is to have to separate Account instances within the Position instance: owningAccount and shortingAccount (with the latter instance possibly being null). Can it be done this way?

If not, it seems like I must handle this situation with many-to-many with Position also holding a List with what I think is the awkwardness of another field in Account which indicates whether it is the owning or shorting Account.

Will the first approach work at all and if not, am I describing in the second approach a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the first approach is not feasible with vanilla JPA - it has no facility for tying associations to a query/attribute.

The second approach is feasible with a many-to-many. You can partly avoid the technical awkwardness by providing accessors for each of the logical associations - `get/setOwningAccount` and `get/setShortingAccount`. The accessors will then hide the technical many-to-many nature of the relation.